# Flow Document with multiple columns-WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on WPF application.
As per requirement, I want to print  content in the  below format

[image]

I am using flow document object for print functionality.
I am using  Section, Paragraph etc.
How I implement this?
How  can I apply multiple column in  Flow Document?

Comment: Did you try this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @MarioStoilov will table let you have overlaps?

Comment: I don't see overlaps in the image the op has given. And no, I don't think it will let you have overlaps

Comment: BTW, FlowDocs don't offer the same layout possibilities WPF does. Column-Designs are very restricted, meaning no Autosizing. One can work-around that but it takes a little effort. Also alignment is not so nice (right-aligned f.e.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming your drawing is not just badly drawn and you really want something like sections with different heights aligned, you can use a table (notice the number of rows and the rowspans):

```
<FlowDocument>
                <Table>
                    <Table.Columns>
                        <TableColumn/>
                        <TableColumn/>
                    </Table.Columns>

                    <TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRow Background="Aqua">
                            <TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Paragraph>Cell with text Cell with text Cell with text Cell with text Cell with text Cell with text Cell with text Cell with text</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell Background="Bisque" RowSpan="2">
                                <Paragraph>Cell 1 with a lot of text Cell 1 with a lot of text Cell 1 with a lot of text Cell 1 with a lot of text Cell 1 with a lot of text</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell Background="Bisque">
                                <Paragraph>Cell 2 with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                           <TableCell Background="Bisque" RowSpan="2">
                                <Paragraph>Cell 2 with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell Background="Bisque">
                                <Paragraph>Cell 1 with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text with a lot of text</Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>

            </FlowDocument>
```

which outputs:
[image]